# How to fix hatched symbol in polygons?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, editing

I want to create polygons which contain the hatch in this picture. Diagonals must intersect in the middle of squares. But when I change scale, the intersection moves. How can I fix the intersection? If you know any other possibilities, please advise me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might have better luck using **Marker Fill Symbols** instead of line fill symbols. In the sample below, I used an 'X' and a 'Cross' available in an Esri symbol set.

The first markers I found had fairly heavy line weights; I don't think you can edit those. I was able to find a lighter weight 'Cross' but not a lighter weight 'X'.

Hopefully this will put you on the right track to a solution. In my testing, the symbols do scale in proportion to one another.

[image]